# invalid bundle id on itunes connect cannot be edited

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I need to ask only simple question 345WRG4453.com.appdomain.appname is bundle id for example

in itunes connect I already filled out all info about app but I wrote only com.appdomain.appname in itunes connect 
as bundle id now when I want to edit this bundle id in 
itunes connect its not possible, or I cannot find the 
way how to edit it and when I want to delete app it says 
I will not be able to use the same name of app again
it displays message:

> Are you sure you want to delete this app?
>   Deleting it will permanently remove it from iTunes Connect, along with any associated In-App Purchases. The App Name and SKU will not be reusable, even once the app is deleted. If you have uploaded a binary or set up this app for the iAd Network, your Bundle ID will not be reusable either.

sounds a bit scary I don't want to change the app name in app and I don't want to lose it because its pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

`345WRG4453.` is basically ignored as long as you select the correct profile when you build.